# What workarounds exist for the `:first-child` pseudo class not being sufficient in this example?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some basic HTML...

```
<div id="panel">
    <h3>abc</h3>
    <address>a</address>
    <address>b</address>
    <address>c</address>
</div>
```

...and CSS...

```
#panel address:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e6;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3ASFE/).

I always took `:first-child` to mean *first child of **that** element* (`address` in this example). I realise in the strictest sense the first child would be the `h3` element, but I  always believed that's how it worked.

According to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child), I'm wrong...

> The :first-child pseudo-class matches an element that is the first child element of some other element.

Is there a workaround to selecting the first `address` element without resorting to changing the HTML (i.e. adding a `class` or `id` attribute)?

If I need to modify the HTML, so be it, but I had in the back of my mind that I have overlooked something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a workaround to selecting the
>   first address element without
>   resorting to changing the HTML?

```
#panel h3 + address {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e6;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `:first-of-type`:

```
#panel address:first-of-type { ...
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3ASFE/1/

(this selector isn't implemented in IE8 and below)

Comment: `:first-of-type` has less support than the adjacent sibling selector. For example it's not supported on IE8.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you're not overlooking anything obvious.

Since you're going for CSS3 (with `:first-child`), you can work around with something like that:

```
#panel *:not(address) + address {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e6;
}
```

There's a limitation to this though: it selects **every** `address` tag that is not preceded by another `address` tag, so if you have multiple `<address>`es interleaved with other tags, it won't help you.

You can also use `nth-child` if you know for sure the DOM index of your tags:

```
#panel address:nth-child(2) {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e6;
}
```

**EDIT** I've gone through the [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) reference, and there's an `nth-of-type` selector:

```
#panel address:nth-of-type(1) {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e6;
}
```

Sounds like what you wanted.

Comment: let me see if I read this right, this gets any descendents of `#panel` that aren't an `address` element then gets the next sibling that is an `address` element?

Comment: @mdmullinax, it gets the next sibling _if_ it is an `address` element. The rest of your interpretation is exact (and I also suspect that this is what you meant; I just wanted to clarify in case).

Comment: ah, I did mean that, but nice clarification :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I always though `:first-child` was CSS 2.1, but `:last-child` was CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the [`:nth-of-type` pseudo-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) instead of the `:first-child` pseudo-selector in your case.

```
#panel address:nth-of-type(1) {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e6;
}
```